# grep does not work in removing patterns from a file from a CSV

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file which needs too be cleaned of some URLs. The URLs are in a file say fileA and the CSV fileB(these are huge files of size 6-10 GB). I have tried the following grep command, but it does not work on newer fileB's.

```
grep -vwF -f patterns.txt fileB.csv > result.csv
```

The structure of file A is a single list of URLs like so:

```
URLs (header, single column)
bwin.hu
paradisepoker.li
```

and fileB:

```
type|||URL|||Date|||Domain
1|||https://www.google.com|||1524024000|||google.com 
2|||www.bwin.hu|||1524024324|||bwin.hu
```

The delimiter for fileB is |||

I am open to all solutions including awk. Thanks.

Edit: expected output is the CSV file retaining all rows not matching the domain patterns in fileA

```
type|||URL|||Date|||Domain
1|||https://www.google.com|||1524024000|||google.com
```

Comment: You say your fileB's delimiter is `|||` but can't see it, could you please post samples clearly so that we could get complete picture of your question. Expected sample output is needed too here.

Comment: Please do add expected output sample too along with more details, is it difference you are looking between 2 files?

Comment: Not diff ..but those not matching the domain patterns in fileA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($NF in a)' Input_filea FS="\\|\\|\\|" Input_fileb
```

OR

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($NF in a)' filea FS='\|\|\|' fileb
```

Output will be as follows.

```
type|||URL|||Date|||Domain
1|||https://www.google.com|||1524024000|||google.com
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                                       ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named filea is being read.
  a[$0]                                        ##Creating an array named a whose index is $0(current line).
  next                                         ##next keyword will skip all further statements.
}                                              ##Closing block for condition FNR==NR here.
!($NF in a)                                    ##Checking condition if last field of current line is NOT present in array a for Input_fileb only.
                                               ##if condition is TRUE then no action is mentioned so by default print of current line will happen.
' filea FS="\\|\\|\\|" fileb                   ##Mentioning Input_file names and for fileb mentioning FS should be ||| escaped it here so that awk will consider it as a literal character.
```

Comment: Thanks RavinderSingh13...is this awk liner as efficient as can be...my CSVs are huge!!

Comment: @MallikKumar, it should be good, though it is creating a single array a which will be stored in memory but IMHO I don't think so it should be too bad etc. In my code filea is `URLs (header, single column)` fie and fileb is your other contents file. Since I don't have large data so I didn't test it but should be ok. Let me know?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13...while simplifying the data set, I forgot to mention that there are more columns. But the given set of columns are in correct order..can you change your code for the 4th column (domain)...I tried ($4 in a) but get back the same number of lines as the CSV. I am sure there are some matching domains in the CSV.

Comment: @MallikKumar, then may be what you are trying is NOT 4th field. Try doing `awk -F'\|\|\|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i,$i}}'  Input_file` and see its number there and then you could put it in my code, let me know?