# AWK solution to a pattern negating a CSV

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have file with a list of patterns, which have to be removed from a CSV with a full / partial match against the $5 column (counting from $1).

Have tried `grep -vwF -f <pattern file> <csv file>`

For some reason it does not work. I need an awk solution.

Input File:

```
type|||URL|||Date|||Domain|||Referral URLs|||more columns
1|||https://www.google.com|||1524024000|||google.com|||https://www.google.com||| and more 
2|||www.bwin.hu|||1524024324|||bwin.hu|||http://www.bwin.hu/q=sdlfj||| and more
```

The pattern file might contain:
`bwin.hu` OR `www.bwin.hu` OR `http://www.bwin.hu`

Output Required:

```
1|||https://www.google.com|||1524024000|||google.com|||https://www.google.com||| and more
```

The reason the older post did not work  is that there were  more number columns. My mistake in omitting them.

Comment: **-F, --fixed-strings** - *Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.* It would not work if you have a list of patterns and not literal strings.

Comment: Whats wrong with your yesterday's question - [grep does not work in removing patterns from a file from a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54918784/5291015). This seems to be similar to your last one

Comment: @Mallik Kumar, Kindly post samples of input and expected output along with what you have tried and what din't work too.

Comment: Need some more info on what are the constraint without, a simple `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$5="" #or you pattern modif;$0=$0"";print}' YourFile > NewFile` should be enough

Comment: My bad @Inian, I should have shown some more columns in my earlier post.

Comment: `full match` and `partial match` are mutually exclusive requirements - what does `a full / partial match` mean? Also, patterns are for quilts and knitting, not software - when you say `pattern` above do you mean `string` or `regexp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that clear though, by seeing your samples and attempt I could write this. Could you please try following(also tested with your provided samples only).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="\\|\\|\\|"
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]=$0
  next
}
{
  val=$2
}
{
  flag=""
  for(i in a){
      if(a[i] ~ val){
         flag=1
      }
  }
}
!flag
'  pattern_file  Input_file
```

Few points to be noted:

1- For safer side I have removed space from last of each line in Pattern_file and 2nd field of Input_file(if they are not there then you could remove `sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")` AND `sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",$2)` from above code. I am also removing characters like `()[]` to avoid any errors in matching(while checking condition only, actual contents will be printed in it though).

2- Also I have saved whole file's(pattern one) into an array and then for each line of Input_file I am checking if it is matching any content in array or not, setting flag if matching.

3- If flag is NOT set seems match is not found so printing the content from Input_file then.

Comment: @MallikKumar, glad that it helped you. Request you to note down some points.1- on SO we all are here to learn and help each other so always show your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem(which you are adding in your post I believe). 2- Always mention as many details as possible in your post, basically sample of input and sample of expected output in CODE TAGS. 3- Always use  CODE TAGS for wrapping your samples using `{}` button. Cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Comment: `I am also removing characters like ()[] to avoid any errors in matching` - like what?

Comment: @EdMorton, sorry if it is not  clear, removed `]`,`[`,`)`,`(` I meant sir.

Comment: I'm asking why though.  What's the problem you're trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: @EdMorton, not related to this question but few days back I was working on partial match(somehow little bit related to url matching itself) at that time my data was having `)([]` by which it was failing(with fatal error, don't have exact error with me as of now) so I thought to apply that here too. Though I agree OP has not confirmed it, that's why I specifically mentioned it in post.

Comment: I'd have to see the problem to comment on it but in this case you're just corrupting the input data and could cause the creation of a matching string that didn't actually exist in the input.

Comment: Also, separately - you're removing spaces from the end of $2 unnecessarily as they won't affect any matches, and if you WERE going to remove them from the end then you'd also want to remove them from the beginning, and most importantly doing so with `sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",$2)` is going to cause awk to recompile the record changing every `|||` FS to a blank OFS.

Comment: You're also doing a regexp match so every RE metachar in the first file will be treated as such and so cause false matches. You either need to escape metachars or do a string match instead.

Comment: wrt `I have commented this since OP may not have these characters` - even if he DOES have them then you need to leave them alone. I'm just going to post an answer...

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir, will learn from your answer, thank you for letting know here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189261/discussion-between-ravindersingh13-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want partial, string matches:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS="[|]{3}" }
NR==FNR { a[$0]; next }
{
  for (str in a) {
      if ( index($5,str) ) {
          next
      }
  }
}
1'  pattern_file  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing nice answer.